# Daily AWS Lambda not creating Athena partition, however commands runs successfully

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

I have an Athena database set up pointing at an S3 bucket containing ALB logs, and it all works correctly.  I partition the table by a column called `datetime` and the idea is that it has the format `YYYY/MM/DD`.

I can manually create partitions through the Athena console, using the following command:

`ALTER TABLE alb_logs ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (datetime='2019-08-01') LOCATION 's3://mybucket/AWSLogs/myaccountid/elasticloadbalancing/eu-west-1/2019/08/01/'`

I have created a lambda to run daily to create a new partition, however this doesn't seem to work.  I use the boto3 python client and execute the following:

```
result = athena.start_query_execution(
    QueryString = "ALTER TABLE alb_logs ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (datetime='2019-08-01') LOCATION 's3://mybucket/AWSLogs/myaccountid/elasticloadbalancing/eu-west-1/2019/08/01/'",
    QueryExecutionContext = {
        'Database': 'web'
    },
    ResultConfiguration = {
        "OutputLocation" : "s3://aws-athena-query-results-093305704519-eu-west-1/Unsaved/"
    }
)
```

This appears to run successfully without any errors and the query execution even returns a QueryExecutionId as it should.  However if I run `SHOW PARTITIONS web.alb_logs;` via the Athena console it hasn't created the partition.

I have a feeling it could be down to permissions, however I have given the lambda execution role full permissions to all resources on S3 and full permissions to all resources on Athena and it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Does the lambda have IAM role that allows it to execute the query? Also, go to the "monitoring" tab and check for errors, you should also be able to view the output logs (button: "view logs in cloudwatch") and see if you can identify errors. If you don't, make sure to wrap your code with try/catch and print the error that is thrown.

Comment: Yeh, it previously failed because of this until I gave it full permissions on all resources for Athena.  There aren't actually any errors in the output logs, this is why I'm pretty confused, the logs appear to show the query running successfully

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Athena query execution is asynchronous your Lambda function never sees the result of the query execution, it just gets the result of starting the query.

I would be very surprised if this wasn't a permissions issue, but because of the above the error will not appear in the Lambda logs. What you can do is to log the query execution ID and look it up with the `GetQueryExecution` API call to see that the query succeeded.

Even better would be to rewrite your code to use the Glue APIs directly to add the partitions. Adding a partition is a quick and synchronous operation in Glue, which means you can make the API call and get a status in the same Lambda execution. Have a look at the APIs for working with partitions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-catalog-partitions.html

Comment: Ahh I didn't realise the execution was asynchronous, that explains a lot. Thanks, yeh I'm able to query the execution id and it does look like it's down to permissions (writing to the output location in S3).  This is strange as I have given the lambda role all S3 permissions, but at least I know where to look now, thanks

Comment: It's surprisingly tricky to get the permissions for Athena right if you want to grant minimal permissions (which you should).

Comment: Yeh I got it working eventually, I didn't realise I had to add permissions for Glue as well, it's been a bit of a learning curve last few days!